# matplotlib qt wsl ubuntu qt5

Tags: matplotlib, qt5, jupyter

Faced problems when using a jupyter notebook and tried to do a simple plot using matplotlib.

Hit many errors,
`ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding`

Also tried installing some libraries in my WSL Ubuntu Linux 
`sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx`
But didn't solve the problem:
`ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

After installing other packages I only got from Jupyter a message `Kernel is dead`.

How to solve issue?

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR;

`sudo apt-get install libxkbcommon-x11-0`

More details:

After a lot of googling, what pointed me in the right direction was (this site)[https://forum.qt.io/topic/93247/qt-qpa-plugin-could-not-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb-in-even-though-it-was-found/3] where SGaist's comment of doing

```
$ export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
$ jupyter qtconsole
```

Showed:
`.../site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxkbcommon-x11.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)`

Which can be installed doing:

```
sudo apt-get install libxkbcommon-x11-0
```

And then it all worked....!

Hope this can help someone...